# Using JavaScript to take input from one HTML page and output to another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page with a button to "save the salt and associated tab" which would save the current tab's url and salt into two variables and then append those values into a table on completely another HTML page. However, the associated JavaScript file cannot read the table from the last HTML page to append the variables to. Is there any way to do so?
First HTML:

```
<html>
<h1>Set the number of characters</h1>
    <input id="num"  type = "number" value = "20" name = "value"><br><br>
    
    
<div class="spec_symb"><label><input  id = "spec_symb" name=unit  type=radio value=special>Special symbols</label></div>
<div class="alphanumeric"><label><input checked id = "alpanumeric" name=unit type=radio value=alpahnumeric>Alphanumeric symbols only</label></div>
<br>
<button id="click">Generate</button><br>
    <p id="text" ></p>
    
    
<button id="save">Save the salt with the associated tab opened</button>
<p id="string" ></p>
<p id="url" ></p>
<ul>
  
        <li><a href=navigation.html>Back to the Navigation Menu</a></li>
       
      </ul>

    
    
    <script src="salt_genj.js"></script>
    
    
   
    </html>
```

JavaScript code (salt_gen.js):

```
function saltgen(length) {
    var radio = document.getElementById("spec_symb");
    var salt = "";
    if(document.getElementById('spec_symb').checked == true){
        var symbols = symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()_"}
    else{var symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";}
    
 var slength = symbols.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
       salt = salt + symbols.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * slength));
    }
    return salt;}
document.getElementById("click").onclick = function(){myFunction()};
 function myFunction(){
     document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = saltgen(document.getElementById("num").value);
 }
 
 document.getElementById("save").onclick = function(){anotherFunction()};
 function anotherFunction(){
     
    var salt = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML ;
    var table = document.getElementById("MyTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = url; 
    cell2.innerHTML = salt;
    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function 
    (tabs) {
        url = tabs[0].url;
        
        
    
    });
     

     
    
     return salt;
     
     
 }
```

Last HTML page with the table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<table id="MyTable" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Webstite</th>
          <th>Salt</th> 
          
        </tr>
        
      </table>
      
      <script src="salt_genj.js"></script>
      
    
</html>
```

Comment: Choices would be pass them in url query string or store in storage

Comment: Pass to another HTML page? Do you have CORS access?

Comment: @StackSlave I do not know what CORS is, but my code is intended to function as a Chrome extension

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: @charlietfl I tried local storage via ```localStorage.setItem("vOneLocalStorage", url);
    localStorage.setItem("vTwoLocalStorage", salt);``` on my first JavaScript page then having 
```var urla = localStorage.getItem("vOneLocalStorage ");
        var salta = localStorage.getItem("vTwoLocalStorage ");```
but the variables just turned out to be empy

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted to use it as a Chrome extension. The browser extension has a background.js script, It runs whenever your extension runs and can connect between multiple pages.

You can also use the cookies or storage API.

Comment: Do you mean that I should put my JavaScript code inside the background.js?

Comment: In browser extensions there is a thing called messaging. You can send messages between different scripts of the extension.
The reason why this is done is that different scripts have different permissions. 
For example, the content.js scripts can edit the webpage that it matches with, when the background.js script can't.

However, the background script run's all the time and can communicate with different tabs.

You can use messages to send the data from the content script to the background script. When you go to the other page, you can ask the background script for the message back.

Comment: As I understand, you propose to pass the variables from salt_gen.js to background.js and then somehow fill out the table using background.js. How would you pass the variable from one js script to another?

Comment: Google's API docs are really hard to navigate. I recommend reading the Firefox version. It's nearly the same https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/sendMessage